# JS Add events to a List where rows are added dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, dom

Hi, 
I am inserting rows in a list dynamically. Right now that is happening on a click of button but eventually that data will come from a DB. That works fine!

What I want to do is that once the list is presented to a user, s/he will take the mouse over the desired list item. At that time the item should be highlighted. 
So I want to add mouseover and mouseout event to each row. 
But the event is triggered on the function declaration itself.
Please find the JSfiddle link here:
https://jsfiddle.net/indiaaditya/ycyb9dot/

The problem section is here::

```
function AddEventsToTableForEachRow(tableId) {
  //Get the NodeList
  alert("Function Called!");
  var nodelist = document.querySelectorAll(".classTableElement");
  var lclCntr = 0;
  alert("Elements found:" + nodelist.length);
  //Set ID's for all the elements
  var strInloop = "";
  //This loop sets the ID for each row.
  for (lclCntr = 0; lclCntr < nodelist.length; lclCntr++) {
    strInloop = "tr" + lclCntr;
    nodelist[lclCntr].setAttribute("id", strInloop);
  }
  //This loop adds event for each row.
  for (lclCntr = 0; lclCntr < nodelist.length; lclCntr++) {
    strInloop = "tr" + lclCntr;
    var rowElement = document.getElementById(strInloop);
    rowElement.addEventListener("onmouseover", alert("A"), false);
  }
}
```

Explanation of JSFiddle code:

1. Click on Generate List button to add rows.

2. Click on GlowRecord Button to highlight the first row. Click it again to remove the highlight. This is the desired function on mouseover and mouseout.

3. Click on AddEvents to generate the events. **This is the part of code that is not working**

AddEvents calls

AddEventsToTableForEachRow('tblTestList')

function.
But this function immediately calls the alert function calls in it.

Expected result is that after calling AddEventsToTableForEachRow, the events should be attached to each row and when the mouse mover to the row, alert message should be shown.

In effect, as mentioned before the alert functions inside AddEventsToTableForEachRow are called immediately and no action on mouseover.

For those who question why I have not used jquery:
a. I am a complete novice to JS/HTML/CSS. I am from C/C++ background and have come to this side because of the ease of building the UI with HTML/CSS/JS. 
b. I am learning on the fly and found DOM to be much cleaner and easier to understand.
But after spending 3 days on this issue I am ready for anything and everything. (But will be happier if I get DOM based solution!)

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,
Aditya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding the event listener to every row, just add it once to the table. Then, in your event handler you can use `event.target` to make sure the event happened on the correct element.

```js
function mouseOverHandler(event) {
  var tr = event.target;
  while(tr) {
    if (tr.localName === 'tr') {
      break;
    }
    
    tr = tr.parentNode;
  }
  
  // tr will be null if the `<table>` was the event recipient
  if (tr) {
    console.log(tr.localName, tr.textContent);
  }
}  

function AddEventsToTable(tableId) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
  if (table) {
    table.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOverHandler, false);
  }
}

AddEventsToTable('mytable');
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>row 1, col 1</td>
    <td>row 1, col 2</td>
    <td>row 1, col 3</td>
    <td>row 1, col 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 2, col 1</td>
    <td>row 2, col 2</td>
    <td>row 2, col 3</td>
    <td>row 2, col 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 3, col 1</td>
    <td>row 3, col 2</td>
    <td>row 3, col 3</td>
    <td>row 3, col 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This does cause the event to trigger when your mouse moves over ANY of the tables children, but I use the while loop to convert the event target to the appropriate `<tr>`.

Comment: @Intervalia..Your  solution is definitely the most optimized result. Thanks for taking the effort and responding so promptly. I will need more experience to understand everything that you have written. But thanks a lot for expanding my horizons.

Answer (score 0):

Change `rowElement.addEventListener("onmouseover", alert("A"), false);`

To `rowElement.addEventListener("mouseover", function() { alert("A"); }, false);`

Comment: Thanks! [link]https://jsfiddle.net/indiaaditya/4obL0a6w/ modified code as per your suggestions and a few more additions. @trevor

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question. You want to accomplish something like this.

1. You first generate a row and add to the dom.
2. you want to attach "onmouseover" event and want to simply alert("A").

**What you were doing wrong?**

```
rowElement.addEventListener("onmouseover", alert("A"), false);
```

You were doing everything good but the problem was in your above line of code. **REMEMEBER** you only use "on" with event names like "onmouseover" and "onclick" inside  like `<h1 onclick="doSomething()"></h1>`. But when you use `addEventListener` method you omit the `"on"` from event names.

If you now change `"onmouseover"` to `"mouseover"` your code will still not run as you're expecting it to run. That's because you're calling the function directly in 2nd parameter of `addEventListener` whereas you need to pass a `callback function`. In your case you can simply pass an anonymous function like the line below:

```
rowElement.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    alert("A");
}, false);
```

Now your script will work as expected. I hope my answer is helpful to you.
Have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtzsx94a/).

Comment: Thanks for your time and taking efforts to go in the details. Please find the modified working link here: https://jsfiddle.net/indiaaditya/4obL0a6w/

Comment: So, do you think that your problem has been solved? if so don't forget to accept this answer and upvote it. If you still need any help you can ask here.

Comment: Ha ha.. how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the following line:

```
 rowElement.addEventListener("onmouseover", alert("A"), false);
```

to

```
 rowElement.onmouseover = function() { alert("A"); };
```

Modified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ywvv0brv/

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. https://jsfiddle.net/indiaaditya/4obL0a6w/ is the modified link with some further additions.